# Having trouble using a C library via a Python API: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, c, api

I'm using a Python script in conjunction with a thermocouple and a thermocouple reader. To communicate with the thermocouple reader, which is written in C, I have to use an API. That API is [PyDAQFlex](https://github.com/torfbolt/PyDAQFlex). The thermocouple reader also came with a tester script, written in C. I'm trying to get a temperature reading from the thermocouple reader, but it only outputs the CJC value.

My code:

```
import daqflex

d = daqflex.USB_2001_TC()

def get_temperature():
    return float(d.send_message("?AI{0}:CJC/DEGC").encode("utf-8"))
```

The output of my code:

```
u'AI{0}:CJC/DEGC=23.8'
```

Note: 23.8 is *not* the temperature. That value is the CJC, as seen in the tester script's command line output below. It's related, but not the value I'm looking for.

---

The tester script's code:

http://pastebin.com/Atsdy7X0 (to get the temperature, I press "t" and then "k" because I have a K-type thermocouple).

The tester script's command line output:

http://pastebin.com/jq4Rr4QX (the temperature here is accurate. This is what I want to plug into my script.)

---

The PyDAQFlex script:

https://github.com/torfbolt/PyDAQFlex/blob/master/daqflex/devices.py (see line 105)

The C code for the thermocouple reader:

http://pastebin.com/rEDR9efR (Not included in entirety, only the relevant parts.)

---

I am seriously struggling to see my mistake here. This [exact piece of code](https://github.com/torfbolt/PyDAQFlex/issues/6) appears to have worked for someone else in the PyDAQFlex Github page, so I'm extremely confused. I have emailed the creator of the software, a person in Github with a similar issue as me, and I just spent 6 hours in various IRC chats. Please help me. If it helps, I used parts of [this](http://www.mccdaq.com/TechTips/TechTip-9.aspx) tutorial to install the drivers and things for the thermocouple reader. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If 23.8 is related, but not the right temp, then it is a calibration problem. Could you print what original tester program and pydaqflex send and receive from the device, when calibrating?

Comment: Eugene, I may have phrased this poorly. 23.8 *is* the calibration number (the CJC). It doesn't change, no matter the temperature of the thermocouple: it responds only to changes in the ambient temperature of the room.